# SQL how to compare null = null

Tags: sql

Hi I have the following two tables:

DEP table:

```
Deptarment_id       Dep_name
--------------------
1   Marketing
2   IT
3   Accouting
4   QA
null    Contract
5   BI
```

EMP table:

```
Deptarment_id       Dep_name
--------------------
1   Marketing
2   IT
3   Accounting
4   QA
null    Contract
5   BI
```

If I run the following query,

```
SELECT * FROM CUS left join EMP on Deptarment_id = CUSTOMER_ID;
```

I will get

```
CUSTOMER_ID NAME    Deptarment_id   Dep_name
1   JOE 1   Marketing
3   Chris   3   Accounting
5   John    5   BI
null    Steve   null    null
null    Mary    null    null
99  test    null    null
```

But what I am looking for is something like that. I cannot get the 'Contract' value back.

```
CUSTOMER_ID NAME    Deptarment_id   Dep_name
1           JOE     1               Marketing
3           Chris   3               Accounting
5           John    5               BI
null        Steve   null            Contract
null        Mary    null            Contract
99          test    null            null
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: seems that you missed a table ... cus

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do actually "misuses" the `NULL` value in SQL.  `NULL` is not a specific value; semantically it means that the value is unknown (not missing, but unknown).  Hence, equality doesn't make sense.

Theory is nice, but sometimes we want to treat `NULL` as a legitimate value.  In that case, be explicit:

```
SELECT *
FROM DEP left join
     EMP
     on (DEP.Department_id = EMP.Department_id) or
        (DEP.Department_id is null AND EMP.Department_id is null);
```

I should warn you that `or` in a `join` condition is often a performance killer.  Some databases offer `NULL`-safe comparisons, but that is database-specific.  There are other methods as well, if performance is an issue.

If performance is an issue, please ask *another* question and include:

- Viable sample data
- The query you have tried
- The results you want
- Performance considerations (how large are the tables)

In this question, the sample data doesn't match the query, so I've filled in some details.

Comment: Thank you so much.